# Bootstrap + Webpack are ignoring my bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap into wepback. I'm useing [bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack) for this.

The bootstrap fonts do show up correctly. However all `row` and `container-fluid` classes are ignored.

I investigated the DOM and can confirm that the `bootstrap.css` file is found and the classes are applied to the divs. But it looks as if they have almost no effect.

[image]

I expected the aaaaa and bbbb side by side. Also the sidebar and form should show side by side.

Any ideas what's wrong?

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Angular with Webpack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<h1>Bootstrap + Webpack</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        bbbbbbbbb
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <h1>Sidebar content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <p>Write some text in textbox: <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" /></p>
            <p>Hello {{sometext}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js file:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery';
import angular from 'angular';
import 'bootstrap-webpack';

var ngModule = angular.module('app', []);
```

webpack.config.file:

```
module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty certain you are just using incorrect HTML, for example.

**First group is missing:**

`<div class="container">`

**Second group should be:**

`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">`

Also columns widths are `col-*-*` not `span*`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options